# Decode base64 in python (for example :: Q29ycsOqYQ== into Corrêa)

Tags: python, base64

I have base64 encoded values like **: Q29ycsOqYQ==**
and i tried this code, to decode it to **Corrêa**.

```
import base64
encoded = ': Q29ycsOqYQ=='
data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
print(data)
```

i get this result **b'Corr\xc3\xaaa'**
but the desired result is **Corrêa**.

Answer (score 0):

`ê` is not standard ascii encoding. If you actually print the data in python2.7 it will give you what you want.

Comment: i am using python 3

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the bytes. Turn it into a string

```
import base64
encoded = 'Q29ycsOqYQ=='
data = base64.b64decode(encoded)

s = str(data, encoding='utf-8')
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Corrêa
```